# Does $f(n)\sim g(n)$ imply $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_n f(n)/g(n) = 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1 \leftrightarrow f(n)\sim g(n).$$

My thought: $f(n)\sim g(n) \to \frac{1}{k}\sum \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$ since we can find an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ with $\left|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}-1\right|< \epsilon$ so for all but finite $n$ the ratio $f/g$ is arbitrarily close to $1$.

But I think $\lim_{k \to\infty} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} =1 \nrightarrow f\sim g$
since we could have for example

$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,\dots$

Is this correct?

---

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: But I think $\lim \frac{1}{k}\sum \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} =1 \nrightarrow f\sim g$
since we could have for example 

$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,...$

Everytime you right $\lim \text{of something}=***$ on a statement, you should write: $\lim$ exists and $\lim =***$. Regarding your example, I don't understand what are the indexes of the sum, so it might be possible that the limit doesn't exist and therefore you might not have a counter example.

Comment: @GitGud: I added some indices but I am not sure I follow. The point of the example was that even though the average of the sum might equal 1 the sequence might not have a limit--which would be a counter-example, right?

Comment: Your last point is correct. If  $0=f(n)\ne g(n)$ for an infinite collection $S$ of $n$ such that the asymptotic density of $S$ in $\Bbb N$ is $0,$ (for example $n\in S$ iff $n$ is a perfect square), and if $0\ne f(n)=g(n)$ for all other $n,$ then the LHS limit is $1$ but $\neg (f\sim g).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow $\leftarrow$ is a consequence of Cesáro summation. Whenaver $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}$ also exists and has the same value, but not the other way round

Answer (score 4):

A good example is perhaps the arithmetic mean of the square of the Möbius $\mu$-function. It is well known that
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k \mu(n)^2=\frac{6}{\pi^2},
$$
so that we coud take $f(n)=\mu(n)^2$ and $g(n)=6/\pi^2$ to obtain $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$. But certainly $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(n)$ is not $1$, because the limit does not even exist.

Comment: Yes I think this is a good example. +1

Comment: Thank you, but you had already the idea, I think.

Comment: Or Take $f(n)=\Lambda(n)$ and $g(n)=1$. Then, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$ by PNT but the limit $\lim f(n) \neq 1$